# Доступная аппаратная платформа для экспериментов с RTOS

Tags: микроконтроллеры, arm, freertos

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня есть вопрос. Если вкратце, то неожиданно по работе пришлось столкнуться с совершенно новой для меня темой RTOS. Т.к. натура у меня очень любознательная то для наилучшего погружения в тематику захотелось что-то поковырять для себя на досуге. У нас используется threadX и специфическая железка с армовским процессором. Т.к. ThreadX это вещь проприетарная, то ставить его куда попало не получится. Стал думать есть ли свободные аналоги... наткнулся на FreeRTOS. У меня есть идея что многие моменты вполне могут быть реализованы сходным образом и для домашних экспериментов вполне сойдет. Если я ошибаюсь, то пожалуйста поправьте и подскажите варианты лучше, если возможно.

Так вот, встал вопрос с железом. Я хоть и программист, но от железа далек насколько это вообще возможно и понятия не имею что мне вообще нужно кроме того что нужна какая-то железка (с ARM архитектурой) на которой можно запустить какой-нибудь RTOS (тот же FreeRTOS, например). За ценой особо вопрос не стоит. По возможности железка нужна функциональная и в меру шустрая чтоб эксперименты были интересней. Так же большим плюсом будет если не придется это все ждать полгода из Китая и можно легко купить в каком-нибудь специализированном магазине. Еще, если это возможно, было бы здорово если там не придется ничего паять. Данный пункт не является супер критичным, но если без этого можно обойтись несколько переплатив то я не против.

Буду благодарен любым советам, будь то наводки на конкретные железки, названия книжек которые могут оказаться полезными для новичка в данной области или любые другие полезные мысли и уточнения.

Всем заранее огромное спасибо за любую помощь. А то я даже пока не знаю с какого конца подступиться к такой большой и интересной теме :)

Comment: Чего вы собственно хотите? Запускать программы  под RTOS (в этом случае можно использовать эмуляторы или даже порт RTOS под  винду)  или играться с RTOS именно на  ARM-овской плате?

Comment: Хотелось иметь именно армовскую плату. Я прикупил себе "STM32F746G-DISCO". Пока играться особо некогда было.. но похоже, это то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Берите любую плату Discovery с микроконтроллером STM32, там и набор периферии различный встречается (экраны, гироскопы, микрофоны и т.д.) и ядра ARM от Cortex-M0 до Cortex-M7. Для этих плат есть как готовые примеры, так и возможность очень быстро собрать свой проект на FreeRTOS с нуля.
Ну а если хотите паять, то можно взять вообще любую плату с микроконтроллером ARM (производитель не важен, хоть там "Миландр" или "Цифровые решения") и припаять к ней необходимую периферию самому. Проект можно взять от тех же плат Discovery, но подправить таблицу векторов прерывания и инициализацию периферии.